# C# Release build can't load SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll, interop, visual-studio-2015

I'm building a c# program that uses a local SQLite database to manage some simple data.

I am using the NuGet System.Data.SQLite (x64/x86) v1.0.98.0 - downloaded using the package manager console in Visual Studio Community 2015. Windows 7 64-bit.

I've built and debugged my code using the "Any CPU", x64, and x86 settings and it works fine. After I publish any of these versions though, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

The error occurs here:

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("local-db.sqlite");
sqlite = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=local-db.sqlite;Version=3;"); //Error on this line
```

Suggestions that haven't worked:

- copying the bin/debug/x64 (and x86) folders (They contain versions of Interop.dll) up one directory
- add SQLite.Interop.dll as a project reference (error - can't add as a reference)
- add to project as existing item, set property "Copy to output directory = always". (still gets original error)
- copying the most recent version of Interop.dll to the System.Data.SQLite directory (the directory referenced by my project)

At the very least, it's not failing to load the .dll but failing to **find** it. I don't know my way around dll's but it might work if I know where it's looking. Does anyone have a fix for this? There are a handful of related questions but they are either unanswered or don't work for me.

Comment: I also remember having a (not sure if completely related to Interop.dll) issue with SQLite and as much as I can remember I had to load dynamically the dll for the correct architecture at runtime to solve this issue.

Comment: the x64 and x86 folders need to be next to System.Data.SQLite.dll file, also you need the same version of sqlite and .NET framework I think. Also, you can download from here: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki the recom. dll-s add it reference, and copy the interop to the correct place, I using this and works, OR just add the Sqlite.Core package as a dependency (with NuGet) to the project you are building/running and the dll-s will be copied